# Transient and Persistent fields not being sent to JSP page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, jpa

When sending an Object to a JSP page the persistent and transient fields are left out. I can see on the Java side these variables are filled in with data, but once it gets to the JSP page some of the values are missing, specifically every field that is not mapped to a column.

Group Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groups")
@XmlRootElement
public class Groups {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="groupsSeqGen")
    //TODO: I dont think H2 is having the sequences auto generated. Need to add these manually.
    @SequenceGenerator(name="groupsSeqGen",sequenceName="groups_sequence", initialValue = 10, allocationSize = 100)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")    
    private String name;

    @Column(name="create_date")
    private Date createDate;

    @Column(name="owner_user")
    private String ownerUser;

    @Column(name="is_public")
    private Boolean isPublic;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "ownerGroup")
    private List<Books> books;
}
```

Request Mapping

```
@RequestMapping("/Mygroups")
public ModelAndView getMyGroup() {
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("groups", appservice.findMyGroups()); //This returns the groups!
    mav.setViewName("myGroups");
    return mav;
}
```

My JSP page can read the groups. Just for an idea here is the console output when I print the object.

```
Groups [id=1, name=Club 1, createDate=2019-08-01 00:00:00.0, description=Club 1 desc, isPublic=true, ownerUser=user1]
```

What i've tried.

1. Adding @transient and @XMLTransient tags.
2. Joining columns differently.
3. Changing the Fetch type (This doesnt matter im just changing random things at this point)

The other Odd Part is when I write to the object with a form I can set these fields fine! Maybe its because Javascript is just setting the fields regardless of if it matches and when Java reads it in when it does match it works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot....

It didn't show up in my JavaScript console output because I skipped adding it to the ToString in my Groups class. Once I added it there. I realized I was just referencing it incorrectly in JavaScript.I think I was referencing it as "books" instead of "group.books" and didn't realize because I was printing the object and it wasn't there.